# Programmatically start new TableRow in table

Tags: c#, html, html-table

I am trying to load models and set every model in a separate, `<td>` when I reach 5 `<td>` I want to automatically start a new `<tr>` but it isn't really working with an if statement. Is it possible or should I go for an entire different approach?

Here is my code:

```
<tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <td>
                <img width="200px" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Beheer", new { productId = Model[i].product_id }) " alt="pasfoto"/><br />
                <center><b>@Html.ActionLink(Model[i].naam, "PrProduct", "Categorie", new { id = Model[i].product_id }, null)</b></center>
                <center>€ @Html.Label(Model[i].prijs)</center> 
            </td>
        }
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you maybe forgotten the `C#` tag as well?

Comment: Yah maybe but it is more about the table not about the c# code, could be any kind of code.

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulo operator `%`. Each time `i%5 == 0`, print a row around the `td`

```cs
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    @if(i%5 == 0)
    {
        <tr>
    }
    <td>
        <img width="200px" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Beheer", new { productId = Model[i].product_id }) " alt="pasfoto"/><br />
        <center><b>@Html.ActionLink(Model[i].naam, "PrProduct", "Categorie", new { id = Model[i].product_id }, null)</b></center>
        <center>€ @Html.Label(Model[i].prijs)</center> 
    </td>
    @if(i%5 == 0)
    {
        </tr>
    }
}
```

So you're going to have a table row when `i` is 0, 5, 10, 15, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting an error. I'll try to fix it, thank you for this code.

Comment: It is complaining. the <tr> opening tag will complain about it not closing. It doesn't see the </tr> tag later in the code. thats why all the closing brackets are not seen any I will get a error when running

Comment: To be honest, I need to brush off my knowledge in the whole HTML generation with C#. Can you not get the content of the `td` in a variable and then `if (i%5==0) { <tr> tdContent </tr>} else { tdContent }`. Something like that.

Comment: Thank you got me on the right foot I fixed it with just a small edit. Don't know if it the correct way if you use borders but for me this works: ill drop a answer

Answer (score 1):

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
@if(i%5 == 0)
{
    <tr></tr>
}
<td>
    <img width="200px" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Beheer", new { productId = Model[i].product_id }) " alt="pasfoto"/><br />
    <center><b>@Html.ActionLink(Model[i].naam, "PrProduct", "Categorie", new { id = Model[i].product_id }, null)</b></center>
    <center>€ @Html.Label(Model[i].prijs)</center> 
</td>
}
```

The above code worked for me. Is it not much different from the answer Havelock gave, but it will not close the brackets in the above code if you do not close the html tags within the same if statement. This way may not look as good if you use borders because I think it will display one empty row? But, for me this worked  fine:)